# AutoMapper convert many to many -> one to many

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a many to many relationship in my domain models:

```
public class DeptNumber : TrackedObject {
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DeptJobLink> DeptJobLinks { get; set; }

}

public class DeptJobLink : TrackedObject {
    public long DeptNumberId { get; set; }
    public DeptNumber DeptNumber { get; set; }

    public long JobNumberId { get; set; }
    public JobNumber JobNumber { get; set; }

}

public class JobNumber : TrackedObject {
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DeptJobLink> DeptJobLinks { get; set; }

}
```

I need to use AutoMapper to break this down into a one to many relationship so it fits the models below:

```
public class DeptNoVM : BaseVM {
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<JobNoVM> Jobs { get; set; }
}

public class JobNoVM : BaseVM {
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DeptNoVM Department { get; set; }
    public long DepartmentId { get; set; }
}
```

Here are my automapper profiles but I can't seem to get the JobNumber into the DeptNoVM without the many to many link class:

```
    public class DeptNosProfile : Profile {
        protected override void Configure() {

            Mapper.CreateMap<DeptNumber, DeptNoVM>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Jobs, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.DeptJobLinks.Select(x => x.JobNumber)));

        }

    }

    public class JobNosProfile : Profile {
        protected override void Configure() {

            Mapper.CreateMap<JobNumber, JobNoVM>();
                //.ForMember(dest => dest.Department, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.DeptJobLinks.FirstOrDefault()));
        }

    }
```

I need the DeptNumbers to go into JobNoVM.Department and I need the JobNumbers to go into DeptNoVM.Jobs - the mapping I'm using is causing a "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source".